# PostgreSQL - Foreign Key após importação

Tags: postgresql, administração-postgresql

Tenho um banco de dados em Firebird e estou passando os dados ele para PostgreSQL, então fiz uma aplicação que lê os dados do Firebird e insere os mesmos no PostgreSQL.

O banco de dados é de um supermercado mas tem pouco tempo de uso, o Banco em FB pesa pouco mais de 1Gb, não é um banco tão pequeno, mas está longe de ser grande.

Bem, na aplicação que citei acima, crio o banco de dados em PostgreSQL e logo em seguida eu faço a carga de importação basicamente são inserts, chuto ai uns 3 milhões de registros, nada absurdo.

Entretanto, após inserir,se eu tentar remover um produto que já tenha vendas o banco aceita, não checa a FK... mas se eu drop a FK e recrio ai tudo funciona perfeitamente... E se eu faço um backup/restore também, tudo volta a mais perfeita sintonia...

Acredito que o banco esteja corrompendo ou algo do tipo na importação, a aplicação é feita em C# e uso o NpgSQL, e os inserts são feitos via functions que exeucutam crud.

A pergunta é, este é um problema do PostgreSQL? eu realmente estou quase desistindo do banco, apesar de todo o trabalho que tive pra escrever um banco de quase 150 tabelas na unha para migrar não estou sentindo segurança no mesmo... e olha que estou vindo Firebird...

Answer (score 0):

Eu trabalho com Firebird e Postgres a algum tempo, e a base do meu trabalho é realizar extração de dados de bases Firebird, transforma-los e inserir em bases Postgres.

Sobre o teu problema, pode estar relacionado aos usuários/permissões. Se tu criares tabelas como postgres em um schema do usuário X e der grant all para o user X, você pode inserir dados sem a FK ser respeitada. 
[Fonte](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4249CA09.4000209%40cs.concordia.ca).

O Postgres é uma base com muitos detalhes de configuração, principalmente se comparada com o Firebird. Mas eu amo as duas.
Outro detalhe que eu tenho certeza que vai te ajudar muito. Usa uma ferramenta de extração de dados. Aqui usamos o Spoon da Pentaho (modou de nome para Hitachi Vantara). [Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/postdownload?source=dlp).